# Как сгенерировать числа c#

Tags: c#, ооп

Доброго времени суток! 
Как сгенерировать числа для стека. Функция Generate - ввыводит, но потом не могу отобразить ее через Display()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

interface IStack {
    Boolean Empty();
    object Generate(object element);
    object Pop();
    object Push(object elements);
    object Peek();
    void Display();
    void DisplayAll();
}

class Carriage {
    public int CarriageNumber {
        get; protected set;
    }

    public string CarriageType {
        get; protected set;
    }

    public Carriage(string type, int number) {
        this.CarriageNumber = number;
        this.CarriageType = type;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return CarriageNumber.ToString() + "/" + CarriageType;
    }
}

class Stack : IStack {
    int StackSize;
    int top;
    object[] item;

    public int StackSizeProperty {
        get { return StackSize; }
        set { StackSize = value; }
    }

    public Stack() {
        StackSizeProperty = 10;
        item = new object[StackSize];
        top = 0;
    }

    public Stack(int capacity) {
        StackSizeProperty = capacity;
        item = new object[StackSizeProperty];
        top = 0;
    }

    public bool Empty() {
        if (top == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object Generate(object element) {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter quantity of items: ");
        int qty = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] item = new int[qty];

        for (int elements = 0; elements < qty; elements++) {
            item[elements] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Item " + elements + ": " + item[elements]);
        }

        return "Items have been generated.";
    }

    public void Display() {
        for (int elements = top; elements > 0; elements--) {
            Console.WriteLine("Item " + elements + ": " + item[elements]);
        }
    }

    public object Push(object elements) {
        if (top == StackSize) {
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is full.\n");
            return "Stack is full.";
        }
        else {
            item[++top] = elements;
            Console.WriteLine("Item was been pushed.\n");
            return "item was been pushed.";
        }
    }

    public void Entering(string CarriageType,  int CarriageNumber) {
        Console.Write("\n\tEnter the type of train: ");
        CarriageType = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("\tEnter the number of train: ");
        CarriageNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public object Pop() {
        if (Empty()) {
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is empty.\n");
            return "Nothing.";
        }
        else {
            return item[top--];
        }
    }

    public object Peek() {
        if (Empty()) {
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is empty.\n");
            return "Nothing.";
        }
        else {
            return item[top];
        }
    }

    public void DisplayAll() {
        Console.WriteLine("All items: ");
        for (int elements = top; elements > 0; elements--) {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + item[elements]);
        }
    }

    public void Exit() {
        do{ } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }

    public int Entering() {
        Console.Write("\tEnter the number of train: ");
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

class MainProgramStacks {
    static void Main() {
        Stack FullStack  = new Stack();
        Stack AtypeStack = new Stack();
        Stack BtypeStack = new Stack();

        int mm_choice = 0, type_choice = 0, peek_choice = 0,
            rmv_choice = 0, display_choice = 0, qty = 0,
            CarriageNumberA = 0, CarriageNumberB = 0;
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("- -- ---  - Menu - --- -- -");
            Console.WriteLine("- 1 - Add an element      -");
            Console.WriteLine("- 2 - Peek top element    -");
            Console.WriteLine("- 3 - Remove top element  -");
            Console.WriteLine("- 4 - Display stacks      -");
            Console.WriteLine("- -- ---  -  --  - --- -- -");
            mm_choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (mm_choice) {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    while (type_choice != 4) {
                        Console.WriteLine("- 1 - Add an element to type A: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 2 - Add an element to type B: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 3 - Generate:                 ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 4 -            Exit           ");
                        type_choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        switch (type_choice) {
                            case 1:
                                AtypeStack.Push(new Carriage("a", AtypeStack.Entering()));
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                BtypeStack.Push(new Carriage("b", AtypeStack.Entering()));
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                AtypeStack.Generate(new Carriage("a", qty));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.Clear();
                    while (peek_choice != 3) {
                        Console.WriteLine("- 1 - Peek top element of A type: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 2 - Peek top element of B type: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 3 -             Exit            ");
                        peek_choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        switch (peek_choice) {
                            case 1:
                                AtypeStack.Peek();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                BtypeStack.Peek();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.Clear();
                    while (rmv_choice != 3) {
                        Console.WriteLine("- 1 - Remove element from type A: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 2 - Remove element from type B: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 3 -              Exit          -");
                        rmv_choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        switch (rmv_choice) {
                            case 1:
                                AtypeStack.Pop();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                BtypeStack.Pop();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    FullStack.Pop();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.Clear();
                    while (display_choice != 4) {
                        Console.WriteLine("- 1 - Display elements of type A: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 2 - Display elements of type B: ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 3 - Display all elements:       ");
                        Console.WriteLine("- 4 -            Exit            -");
                        display_choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        switch (display_choice) {
                            case 1:
                                AtypeStack.Display();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                BtypeStack.Display();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                AtypeStack.DisplayAll();
                                BtypeStack.DisplayAll();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int[] item - локальная переменная, object[] item - поле класса

Comment: >>Функция Generate - ввыводит, но потом не могу отобразить ее через Display()<< Кого "её"? Функцию? Что вы подразумеваете под отображением функции?